# Parse string data with json and use it in function

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Here I have two variables:

```
var id = '3, 5 ,16,'; //n number if elements
var naziv = 'fieldY, fieldX, fieldQ,';  //same number of strings like number of id
```

I need to use this variables in select2 plugin so I need to create a array from this data, like this:

```
[{id: "3", title: "fieldY"},{id: "5", title: "fieldX"},{id: "16", title: "fieldQ"}] ...
```

so then I can use this variable id, naziv into select2 function:

```
$("#e6").select2("data", [{id: "3", title: "fieldY"},{id: "5", title: "fieldX"},{id: "16", title: "fieldQ"}]);
```

so how I can transform `id, naziv` into format which I need ?

**UPDATE: id, naziv musr be without quotes, so without "id" just id... thats the problem**

Comment: Why don't you simply write the variable differently to fit?

Comment: becouse in my database are strings in this format etc. 1, 4, 7, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the id field has a type and should be `var id = '3, 5, 16,'`.

We can convert the strings into arrays with `.split(', ')`, but we'll need to remove the trailing commas from the end. We can do that with `.substr(0, [strvariable].length - 1)` if we know it's always going to have a trailing comma, or we can simply check with `[strvariable].lastIndexOf(',') == ([strvariable].length - 1) ? [strvariable].substr(0, [strvariable].length - 1) : [strvariable]`.
The final code for this segment will end up like this.

```
var idArr = (id.lastIndexOf(',') == (id.length - 1) ? id.substr(0, id.length - 1) : id).split(', ');
var nazivArr = (naziv.lastIndexOf(',') == (naziv.length - 1) ? naziv.substr(0, naziv.length - 1) : naziv).split(', ');
```

So, now we have two associative arrays that we just need to loop through to create our objects. We'll create an array to hold our objects and stuff all of them in there.

```
var objHold = [];
for(var i=0,length=idArr.length;i<length;i++)
{
    if(idArr[i] && nazivArr[i]) // make sure both arrays have a value
    objHold.push({id: idArr[i], title: nazivArr[i]});
}
```

Now you can call `$("#e6").select2("data", objHold);`

Final code

```
var id = '3, 5, 16,'; //n number if elements
var naziv = 'fieldY, fieldX, fieldQ,';  //same number of strings like number of id
var idArr = (id.lastIndexOf(',') == (id.length - 1) ? id.substr(0, id.length - 1) : id).split(', ');
var nazivArr = (naziv.lastIndexOf(',') == (naziv.length - 1) ? naziv.substr(0, naziv.length - 1) : naziv).split(', ');
var objHold = [];
for(var i=0,length=idArr.length;i<length;i++)
{
    if(idArr[i] && nazivArr[i]) // make sure both arrays have a value
    objHold.push({id: idArr[i], title: nazivArr[i]});
}
$("#e6").select2("data", objHold);
```

Comment: I need to id and naziv be withou quotes , without ""

Answer (score 1):

try this :  http://jsbin.com/ridoqupi/4/edit

```
var id = '3, 5 ,16,'; //n number if elements
var naziv = 'fieldY, fieldX, fieldQ,';  

var g1=id.split(',');
var g2=naziv.split(',');

var g=[];

for (var i=0;i<g1.length;i++)
  {
    if (g1[i]&&g2[i])
    g.push({id:g1[i].trim() , title:g2[i].trim()})
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(g))

 //result  : [{"id":"3","title":"fieldY"},{"id":" 5 ","title":" fieldX"},{"id":"16","title":" fieldQ"}]
```

Comment: why is my data dangerous... is beter to add into database with some other separator etc. 'and' keyword ?

Comment: ", " <--- VERY dangerous - from comment above from @Royi Namir

Comment: @gmaestro cuz counting on the space is dangerous.

Comment: notice that trim is for ie9+. use this to add it :`if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
}`

Comment: now i have: [{"id":"3","naziv":"Vocnjak N"},{"id":"11","naziv":"Moja parcela N"},{"id":"","naziv":""}] , I need to id and naziv be without ""

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
var s1 = id.split(/,\s*/);
var s2 = naziv.split(/,\s*/);
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
    if (s1[i] && s2[i]) result.push({"id":parseInt(s1[i].trim()),"text":s2[i].trim()});
}

$("#parcele1").select2({ data:result });
```

result will now return the desired result no matter where the comma is placed and no matter if there is a whitespace before/after each comma.

Comment: `", "` <--- VERY dangerous

Comment: why is my data dangerous... is beter to add into database with some other separator etc. 'and' keyword ?

Comment: You data is not especially dangerous, the way i split your data (before i edited my post) was dangerous.

Comment: You still need to take care on the last element in : `["3", "5 ", "16", ""]`

Comment: Empty values should no longer be pushed now.

Comment: @gmaestro It should be fully functional right now, including trimming.

Comment: now I cal this with :      $("#parcele1").select2("data", [result]);
 but dont work

Comment: $("#parcele1").select2({
    data:[result]
});

Comment: I need to id and naziv be without quotes, so like this : [{id: "3", title: "fieldY"},{id: "5", title: "fieldX"},{id: "16", title: "fieldQ"}]);

Comment: "id" should have quotes, as it is a key. However, i added `parseInt()` to the id value. Try now.